# How to automate Redshift snapshot creation and resume cluster from snapshot at a particular time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, aws-cli, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I want some solution where a CloudWatch rule triggers the lambda function that takes a snapshot and shutdown the cluster at the given time, and resume the cluster from the created snapshot at another time.

This way a lot money can be saved.

As of now, AWS does not provides such solutions. Cluster Pause and Resume can be done by scheduling but still we need to pay for the storage resource of the cluster.

Comment: What is stopping you from doing what you suggest? where is your question? what have you tried and what error/problem do you run into?

Answer (score 1):

This is quite doable and did it at my last company. Just call the API functions to delete cluster w/ snapshot and start cluster from snapshot.  I also connected it to cloudwatch events to start / stop on schedules and to slack for on-demand starts and stops.

So what are you looking for?  Boto3 calls can do all that you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks @Bill for your answer! Yes, I am also looking for the Boto3 calls. Can you please give  more hints how to proceed to solve this problem. I greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: So start by looking at https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift.html paying attention to calls delete_cluster() and restore_from_cluster_snapshot().  These calls can be made from a Lambda function and the restore will need a number of arguments like the parameter group and security group - just restore the cluster a few times manually and you will have all the info you need.    Remember that after the restore call is made it will take a few minutes before the cluster is available - I wrote a polling step function to alert me when it became available.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Snapshots and paused cluster storage are charged at the same rate. Recommend using a pause and resume schedule.

Comment: Thanks Joe!  After pausing, Redshift releases all the compute resources and only have to pay for the storage. But here the storage is DISK, which price is higher than S3. Amazon Redshift stores snapshots in an internally managed Amazon S3 bucket, which has lower cost. I am not sure the price would be same for the snapshot (i.e.,in S3) and storage (i.e, volume). Please share if the AWS documentation discloses that Snapshots and paused cluster storage are charged at the same rate.